# fixing loader ajax to show only for router

Tags: angularjs

I want to show an ajax indicator when a sub page is loading inside ng-view. I want to show it only for routers but the code snippet below is showing ajax indicator for all ajax requests, how to fix it?

```
directive('loading',   ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs)
            {
                debugger;
                scope.isLoading = function () {
                    debugger;
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                };

                scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (v)
                {
                    debugger;
                    if(v){
                        elm.show();
                    }else{
                        elm.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Usage

```
<div class="ajax-ngview" data-loading></div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

I am looking something like

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/MCT/home/home',  //when this url is being loaded show a particular ajax activity gif
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.setActiveMenuMod('mct-mod');
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is that you can use http Interceptors to intercept $http requests and react to it

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
return {
 'request': function(config) {
     //trigger data-loading
  },

  'response': function(response) {
     // same as above
  }
};
```

});

Comment: Actually I just want to show ajax when an ajax activity is in progress for $routeProvider.